# Create session variable in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to create a session variable on my jquery mobile page for authentication.

i have a login page.

when user login to a session should be created.

```
$("#submit").click(function (e) {

 session('name')=$('#name').val();

});
```

and check that if session variable exist in each page.

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#homePage", function( event ) {
if(!session('name'))
{
$.mobile.changePage("#loginPage");
}
```

When sign out button clicked it must remove.

Is it possible? pls help

Comment: Sessions are Server side component not the client side component. You can use the cookie to work on client side.

Comment: Depending on the type of information that the login session is protecting, you may not want to leave the "keys" just sitting entirely on the client side!  Anyway, jstorage is a handy client side storage box (http://www.jstorage.info/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a client side based solution that uses [jstorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) to store the session data.  You will also need the [json2](http://www.JSON.org/json2.js) library as [jstorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) requires it.

There really is no security with a solution like this so do not use it to try and prevent access to anything sensitive, etc..

**This is the code that goes in the head .. /head section of every page:**

```
<!-- load the css used by the jquery-mobile library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />

<!-- load the json2 library (required for jstorage use) -->
<script src="json2.js"></script>

<!-- load the jquery library -->
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- load the jstorage library -->
<script src="jstorage.js"></script>

<!-- load the js that binds to various jqm events here, BEFORE loading jqm -->
<script src="example_client_session.js"></script>

<!-- load the jquery-mobile (jqm) library -->
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

**The 'example_client_session.js' file contains the following:**

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function(event) {

    var session = $.jStorage.get('session', ''); // syntax: $.jStorage.get(keyname, "default value")

    // See: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3384
    var activePage = $(event.target);

    // if the current page is not the login_page *and* there is no session *then* redirect to the login_page
    if(activePage[0].id != 'login_page' && (!session) ){

        $.mobile.changePage("#login_page");

    }

    // if the current page *is* the login_page *and* there is already a session *then* redirect to landing page
    if(activePage[0].id == 'login_page' && session ){

        $.mobile.changePage("whatever_landing_page.htm");

    }

});



$(document).on("pageinit", "#login_page", function() {
    console.log('pageinit event - login_page only');

    $('#login_button').on('click', function(e){
        console.log('click event for login_button');

        e.preventDefault();

        // .. do whatever validation here
        if($('#name').val()){

            // .. if good to go, create the session
            $.jStorage.set('session', $('#name').val(), {TTL: 28800000});
            // syntax:  $.jStorage.set('keyname', 'keyvalue', {TTL: milliseconds}); // {TTL... is optional time, in milliseconds, until key/value pair expires}

            // redirect to whatever page you need after a successful 'login'
            $.mobile.changePage("whatever_landing_page.htm");

        }else{

            $('#login_message').html('<strong>Please provide a name before proceeding</strong>');

        }

    });

});
```

**And finally, the login_page looks like this:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="login_page" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b">



   <div data-role="header">Header Content</div>

   <div data-role="content">
        Please Login

        <div id="login_message"></div>

        <form name="login_form" id="login_form">

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="name">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
        </div>

        <input type="submit" id="login_button" name="login_button" value="Login" />


        </form>

    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">Footer Content</div>

</div>
```